# Strange Scroll Bar

Tags: css, scrollbar

I love the scroll-bar I've seen on this site but it doesn't seem to work. The scroll appears beautifully but there's a grey gap beside it and it effects other items on the page by making them square. I don't quite know what I've done wrong...

```
/* SCROLLBAR */

body {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
 background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

My site's http://www.dragonclub.co.uk
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove position from body, inlcuding top left bottom and right.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {margin-right: -10px;}
```

or

```
body {right: -10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `body {overflow-y: scroll}`.

Regardless of the size of the page, `scroll` permanently places a "default" scrollbar on the page which is actually shoving the other aside. You should use `auto` instead, or remove the style entirely.

As for your comment about other elements looking square... how should they look?